# NPM Installation options

Tags: node.js, npm

I am making an npm package that does some language parsing and static file building. I want to leverage existing libraries for the parsing and building but I do not want to require all of the libraries as dependencies because it is not likely that the consumer will need support for eveyry language.

I haven't been able to find a way to prompt the user at install time and conditionally install certain dependencies.

Currently I am omitting language-specific dependencies altogether and prompting the user at runtime to install them for the language(s) they are using.

Is there a better/standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to go about this is plugins. That's how build tools do it.

Plugins means telling the user to install your package alongside the necessary packages that deal with "languages" or whatever your optional dependencies are.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/

http://gruntjs.com/plugins

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Comment: I am not creating a plugin though or creating a platform for others to create plugins. I just want the user to specify 'javascript' when they install my package so I can install esprima and escodegen and not other packages for languages they don't use. According to the article you linked, peer dependencies would still cause all listed packages to be installed.